# Retrieve a 2 items from a list at a time in loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, python-2.7

how can I retrieve 2 items from a loop at a time?

I have this list

```
lst = ['url1', 'value1', 'url2', 'value2', ... ]
```

I want to loop it and for every iteration I want to fetch 2 items.

```
for x in lst:
    x # here x loops 1 by one.
```

I am using bellow solution

```
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    url = lst[i]
    val = lst[i+1]
```

I wan to know is there anything built in?

Comment: It seems like a dictionary or a tuple would be better used here, judging from the way you labeled your data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> lst = ['url1', 'value1', 'url2', 'value2']
>>> i = iter(lst)
>>> zip(i,i)
[('url1', 'value1'), ('url2', 'value2')]
```

or, probably more useful:

```
>>> i = iter(lst)
>>> dict(zip(i,i))
{'url1': 'value1', 'url2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: First solution is what I need.